# ANN implementation with Python OpenCV for handwriting recognition

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, handwriting-recognition

There are 350 samples for each of 50 letters. Neural network has 3 layers. Input layer 400(20*20 images), hidden 200 and output 50. The training parameters I've used are:

```
max_steps = 1000
max_err = 0.000001

condition = cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS

criteria = (condition, max_steps, max_err)

train_params = dict(term_crit = criteria, 
              train_method = cv2.ANN_MLP_TRAIN_PARAMS_BACKPROP, 
              bp_dw_scale = 0.1, 
              bp_moment_scale = 0.1)
```

What are the the optimal values I can use for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I fear you'll have to choose them manually by trial & error.

These values depend on lots of factors and, as far as I know, there's no formula to compute them. When I start training a new ANN, I just run it over and over again changing these parameters slightly each time.

Comment: Isn't there at least a way to narrow down the range of values for each?

Comment: @sope, with backpropagation - I'm not aware of any. You can use [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno_algorithm), it could perform better.